# Is my understanding of Eta reduction correct?

Tags: lambda-calculus

In my script I have the following term:

> x => y => both (x) (y)
>
> This is reduced to
> both

My interpretation is that this function (the whole term) takes two arguments and returns a function and two variables, but these aren't used by the function thus we can remove them? Is this interpretation correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> returns a function and two variables

No, it returns the result of applying the function to these two arguments. This result of course uses the arguments.

Instead, consider this. I don't know what function `both` is, but let's say it works on numbers. if you calculate e.g. `(x => y => both x y) 1 2`, it will be:

```
(x => y => both x y) 1 2 ==
(y => both 1 y) 2 ==
both 1 2
```

And if you replace `1` and `2` by anything else, you'll still get the same result if you apply both `x => y => both x y` and `both` to the same arguments.

So `x => y => both x y` and `both` are two different expressions which represent the same function and you can simplify the first to the second.

Comment: But isn't the procedure your are describing Beta reduction and not Eta redcution?

Comment: No. Each step of the above calculation is a beta-reduction, true. But you can't beta-reduce `x => y => both x y` itself; it isn't an application of a lambda to something.

Comment: I added another sentence in the end, maybe it makes it clearer?